# How deal with colors in large data sets

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

I'm trying to make a graph using [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) for a data set that it's not large in number of rows but in categories.
I got around 30-60 categories (which results in 30-60 plots) and currently I'm using `tab20` [colormap](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html), however I would like to know if is it possible to exist other colormap or other technique to to get divergent colors for large number of categories than 20.

Comment: Do you really need to have a different color for all of them? If you use too many colors, they lose importance. If you produce one plot per category anyways, what's the point of having a separate color for each one?

Comment: Hi @brimbo thanks for the comment. Indeed I asked myself this question, and the answer would be yes, because, for example, one of the graphs its related to information along the years for each state (in the case of Brazil 27 states). I thought to group the states by region and plot separately, but I guess it's not working well to compare multiple plots.

Comment: Maybe you also need to reconsider the message that you want to bring across. You could use only the ones that are highly different than the average or group the "boring ones" together as an average curve.